# Having trouble customizing the color of the calendar overlay

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-calendar, style.css

I was reached out by a customer to make the colors on their SharePoint calendar more customized since the default was pretty bad. I tried to follow the steps and even the video from [this link](https://www.spsimply.com/home/2018/6/2/sharepoint-customize-the-colors-for-calendar-overlays).

When I go to the drop down, the thumbnail displays the custom colors but after selecting them, it still displays the default colors. I don't know why the change isn't taking effect but I would like to have it fixed. I tried to reach out to the creator of the article, but I also noticed that the previous comments haven't been responded in over a year which I do not have that much time to wait for.

If anyone can assist, I greatly appreciate it!